# Return from except to try in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, return, try-catch, try-except

How I can realize return from except to try with new parameters?

Code for example:

```
a = None
b = None
f = open('strings.data')    #1..99

for k in range(len(g)):
    k = int(k)
    #label: trytry
    try:
        main(cc = g[k], aa = a, bb = b)
    except error as e:
        if error.get('error_code') == 14:
            a = 1
            b = 2
            #goto trytry
    else:
        a = None
        b = None
        print(str(k) + 'Added #')
```

Result of work:

```
7  Added # 
8  Added # 
9  Added # 
10  Added # 
12  Added # 
13  Added # 
14  Added #
```

The eleventh element catch the error, so not processed.
I'm hope for your help. Thanks!

Comment: `k` is already an `int`, you don't need to `int()` it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variable `attempts` to try the logic again up to `attempts` number of times:

```
a = None
b = None
f = open('strings.data')    #1..99

for k in range(len(g)):
    k = int(k)
    #label: trytry
    attempts = 5
    while attempts:
        try:
            main(cc = g[k], aa = a, bb = b)
        except error as e:
            if error.get('error_code') == 14:
                a = 1
                b = 2
                #goto trytry
                attempts -= 1
        else:
            a = None
            b = None
            print(str(k) + 'Added #')
            break
```

If the code succeeds without errors then the first attempt was successful and no further attempts are needed. But if an error does occur then you can try it again until it succeeds or until the maximum number of attempts is reached (whichever comes first).

Comment: Thank you very much! 
It will serve.